# Use suffix for twig

Tags: php, twig

I have two twig array like arrayA,arrayB

```
arrayA = {1,2,3,4}
arrayB = {10,20,30,40}
```

each elements of arrayA is correspondent to arrayB.

then

```
{%  for a in arrayA %}
{{ a }}
{{ arrayB[]}} <- I want to show the element of arrayB in order here
{% endfor %}
```

It's not difficult question for php.

you can use `for (i=0;i < count(arrayA);i++){ arrayB[i]..`

However I am not sure how to do this in twig.

Comment: `{% for key, value in arrayA %}{{ arrayB[key] }}{% endfor%}`

Comment: probably just `{{ arrayB[a-1]}}` ?

Comment: @DarkBee your way works well.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo ,but it might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the [loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

```
{{ arrayB[loop.index0] }}
```